# Concatenating two data frames on large no. of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have to Use concatenate function for large no. of columns. Let say this my function.

```
pd.concat([mdf1[['user','tag1','tag2','tag3','tag4']].groupby(['user']).agg(sum)
```

Here I have large no. of tags so I want my function to take all the columns say after 'tag1' how can I do that?
mdf1

```
        user        page_name            category  tag1  tag2  tag3
0  random guy        BlackBuck   Transport/Freight     1     1     0
1   mank nion        DJ CHETAS  Arts/Entertainment     0     1     1
2  random guy      GiveMeSport               Sport     1     0     1
3   mank nion  Gurkeerat Singh      Actor/Director     1     0     1
```

mdf2

```
          user         page_name            category  tag1  tag2  tag3
0   pop rajuel      WOW Editions        Concert Tour   NaN   NaN   NaN
1  Roshan ghai            MensXP  News/Media Website   NaN   NaN   NaN
2    mank nion     Celina Jaitly             Actress   NaN   NaN   NaN
3   pop rajuel      500 Startups            App Page   1.0   0.0   1.0
4  Roshan ghai          No Abuse           Community   NaN   NaN   NaN
5   random guy  Analytics Ninja    Insurance Company   NaN   NaN   NaN
6   pop rajuel  Biswapati Sarkar      Actor/Director   1.0   0.0   0.0
7  Roshan ghai     the smartian        Public Figure   0.0   1.0   1.0
```

output

```
      user  tag1  tag2  tag3
0    mank nion   1.0   1.0   2.0
1   random guy   2.0   1.0   1.0
2  Roshan ghai   0.0   1.0   1.0
3    mank nion   NaN   NaN   NaN
4   pop rajuel   2.0   0.0   1.0
5   random guy   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

only difference where I want to apply is there I have a large no. of columns i.e. 'tag4' 'tag5' . so I want my code to  take all the column after 'tag1' here in this code i am basical concatenating the 2 mdf after after grouping it on user and summing them.

Comment: Can you add sample of data (5,6 rows) and desired output?

Comment: @jezrael added , any thing else required to explain my question?

Comment: But why do you need filter columns? You need sum only some columns and other not?

Comment: Because if use `df = pd.concat([mdf1,mdf2])` and `print (df.groupby('user', as_index=False).sum())`, then there is some problem?

Comment: @jezrael i need to add all the column except that 'page_name' and 'category'

Comment: Super, so give me a minute

Comment: let me try that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregating [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df = pd.concat([mdf1,mdf2])
print (df)
          user         page_name            category  tag1  tag2  tag3
0   random guy         BlackBuck   Transport/Freight   1.0   1.0   0.0
1    mank nion         DJ CHETAS  Arts/Entertainment   0.0   1.0   1.0
2   random guy       GiveMeSport               Sport   1.0   0.0   1.0
3    mank nion   Gurkeerat Singh      Actor/Director   1.0   0.0   1.0
0   pop rajuel      WOW Editions        Concert Tour   NaN   NaN   NaN
1  Roshan ghai            MensXP  News/Media Website   NaN   NaN   NaN
2    mank nion     Celina Jaitly             Actress   NaN   NaN   NaN
3   pop rajuel      500 Startups            App Page   1.0   0.0   1.0
4  Roshan ghai          No Abuse           Community   NaN   NaN   NaN
5   random guy   Analytics Ninja   Insurance Company   NaN   NaN   NaN
6   pop rajuel  Biswapati Sarkar      Actor/Director   1.0   0.0   0.0
7  Roshan ghai      the smartian       Public Figure   0.0   1.0   1.0

print (df.groupby('user', as_index=False).sum())
          user  tag1  tag2  tag3
0  Roshan ghai   0.0   1.0   1.0
1    mank nion   1.0   1.0   2.0
2   pop rajuel   2.0   0.0   1.0
3   random guy   2.0   1.0   1.0
```

Columns `page_name` and `category` are omited, because [automatic exclusion of nuisance columns](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns).

Comment: yes this works all of this i am doing for this problem which one of freind have posted but have not been answered by anyone if you can have a look on that [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630289/taking-two-and-more-data-frames-and-extracting-data-on-unique-keys-in-python]

Comment: @Merlin please check again the link We are working code is working fine fut taking some time if applied on big data set so, so there is huge scope of improvement. If you can suggest them.

Comment: Ok, I try remove loops from another question, please check it.